# error in calcull integral with trapz

Tags: matlab, integral

I want to calculate a time vector (testime) so I applied the following equation

[image: formula]

to  integrate over a vector `cp(t)` and calculate   but I will see an error which is

> "In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be
>   the same".
>
> Error in integraletest (line 12)
>       testime(i)=1/vs(i) +trapz(pas,vs(i))."

I should mention that:

- All vectors have the same size (345600);
- `vs` is a vector containing 27 values.(vs est le cp dans la formule)

  ```
  load ('vleurcpetcm ','vs','k')

   pas= [0,5,15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95,105,115,135,165,...
        195,225,255,285,375,525,675,825,975,1125,1350,1650];


   for i=1:27
       testime(i)=  1/vs(i) +trapz(pas,vs(i))
   end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention how to use trapz function and read carefully its manual: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html

The error you get indicates, that the length of your result (right side) changes over the iterations, but the left side should remain the same (number of elements in testime(i)). This is because you do not use the function trapz properly.

If you wish to integrate over a particular interval, you should specify the grid you want to integrate over and not the final point (as you try to do by providing a single element as limit "sr(i)" which is treated by the trapz function as a dimension.

What you should do is the following:

integrate function "pas" over interval [0 i]  = trapz(0:(i-1),pas(1:i))

assuming, the spacing of your interval is of unit length. If not, define your vector of spacing (instead of 0:(i-1)) accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i remplace you code but another error presnt"  Error using permute
ORDER contains an invalid permutation index.

Error in trapz (line 43)
  y = permute(y,perm);

Error in integraletest (line 12)
    testime(i)=1/vs(i) +trapz(0:(i-1),pas(1:i))"

Comment: i went to integrate like the equation cp (vs in my code)in the intervalle of t (pas in my code).what do you mean by vector of spacing please

Comment: i use this code and  it worked but idont khnow if it is right please what do you think?                                                                          testime=cumtrapz(pas,vs)